# MATLAB: 'If' any row of a part of an array contains a value

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is there any way of shortening line #2 of the code below?

```
for i = 1:length(dataStructure)
    if dataStructure(1,i) == 100000000 || dataStructure(2,i) == 100000000 % this line
        dataStructure(:,i) = NaN;
    end
end
```

I would have thought the following would suffice (but this doesn't work):

```
if dataStructure(:,i) == 100000000
```

In other words, how do I check whether a number exists in a given column of an array? The issue here is that I cannot predict whether dataStructure will have one or two rows, and so can't use a nested for loop, since it would cause an error every time dataStructure only had one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the loop:

```
dataStructure(:,any(dataStructure==1e8,1) = NaN;
```

this is called logical indexing, more info: [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing) and [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
if any(dataStructure(:,i) == 100000000)
```